# C# AT Command AT+CPBS=xxx trouble

Tags: c#, at-command, modem

AT Command -  `AT+CPBS=xxx` returns an empty contact name

my code:

```
string req(int comport, string command)
{           
    if (sp.IsOpen)
    {
        sp.Close();
        sp = new SerialPort();
    } 

    sp.PortName = "COM" + comport; //  на каком порту модем

    try
    {
        sp.Open();

        //sp.DataReceived += port_DataReceived;
    }
    catch
    {
        return "Не могу открыть порт";
    }

    sp.WriteLine(command + "\r\n");
    Thread.Sleep(500); //пауза перед приемом ответа

    return sp.ReadExisting();

}

private void button21_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    //телефонная книга
    int maxpb;

    string pb = req(comport,"AT+CPBS?");
    MessageBox.Show(pb);
    string maxpb_s = Regex.Match(pb, "(?<=SM\",)(.*)(?=,)").ToString();
    maxpb = int.Parse(maxpb_s);
    List<string> contacts=new List<string>();

    //=макс тел книги, включая посл. контакт
    for (int i = 1; i <= maxpb;i++ )
    { 
        contacts.Add ( req(comport,"AT+CPBR="+i));
        MessageBox.Show(contacts[i-1]);
    }
}
```

Returned instead of the spaces equal to the number of characters in a name
in the standard program for the modem with the names of all right

Look at the picture
[image: Problem]

Comment: What is current selected character set (AT+CSCS) ? Did you try to compare your requests to modem with another program's (using some kind of serial port monitoring software)?

Comment: I tried   http://rghost.ru/74rhYRHmH/image.png  +CSCS: "IRA"

Comment: @andw , Thanks for the hint,   I solved the problem of the so- req(comport, "AT+CSCS=\"UCS2\"");

string[] zz = contacts[i - 1].Split(',');   zz [3] - Returns the name ucs2, which then decodes the normal name